Como criar um link personalizado para Google Reviews com o nome do colaborador pré-preenchido?
Estou trabalhando em um sistema para a minha empresa onde premiamos os colaboradores mais bem avaliados no Google Reviews a cada mês. Para isso, coletamos as avaliações e contabilizamos os nomes mencionados. No entanto, enfrentamos um problema: muitos clientes digitam o nome do colaborador de maneira errada ou incompleta, dificultando a identificação correta dos colaboradores avaliados.
Gostaria de saber se é possível criar um link personalizado que já venha pré-preenchido com o nome do colaborador que compartilhou o link, facilitando assim a identificação correta nas avaliações.
O que já tentei:
Bots com Python e JavaScript: Tentei automatizar o processo de login e preenchimento usando bots, mas o Google bloqueia essas tentativas de login, como era de se esperar.
Pesquisa sobre APIs: Pesquisei sobre possíveis APIs do Google que permitam essa funcionalidade, mas não encontrei uma solução clara.
Pergunta:
Existe uma maneira de criar um link personalizado para Google Reviews que já venha com o nome do colaborador pré-preenchido? Se sim, como posso implementar isso de forma eficiente e segura?
Detalhes adicionais:
Utilizamos um sistema web desenvolvido em [tecnologias que você está usando, como React, Node.js, etc.].
O volume de avaliações cresceu exponencialmente, tornando inviável a identificação manual dos colaboradores mencionados.
Qualquer solução que envolva APIs do Google ou outras ferramentas que possam ajudar seria bem-vinda.
Desde já, agradeço pela ajuda!

Esta pergunta já foi postada e lá foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original).
